# Change #define value during compilation by Makefile argument C

Tags: c, makefile

my main file looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "./header/minus.h"
#include "./header/plus.h"
#include "./header/screen.h"

#ifndef DBG
    #define DBG 0
#endif

int main(void) {
    int a, b, c;
#if DBG
    printf("Hello World\n");
    printf("Goodbye World\n");
    printf("minus %d\n", minus(18, 16));
#endif
    screen(1);
    printf("Insert a:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Insert b:\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Plus: %d\n", plus(a, b));
#if DBG
    printf("main a: %ld , %ld\n", a, &a);
    printf("main b: %ld , %ld\n", b, &b);
#endif
    c = minus(&a,&b);
    printf("Minus: %d\n", c);
    screen(2);
    return 1;
}
```

I am trying to change `DBG` define during makefile compilation (as an exercise) to activate/deactivate extra messages.

My **Makefile** looks like

```
SOURCES =               \
    ./src/main.c        \
    ./src/screen.c      \
    ./src/plus.c        \
    ./src/minus.c       \
INCLUDES = -I./src/header
VERBOSE := 1
OBJDIR=./src
#DEBUG switch
DBGFLAGS = -DDBG=1
LDFLAGS += -W $(INCLUDES)
CC=gcc

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(DBGFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@

#preprocessor output
%.i : %.c
    $(CC) $(DBGFLAGS) -E $< -o $@
OBJS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

#all object files without compilation
.PHONY: compile-all
compile-all: $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(DBGFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -c

.PHONY: build
build: t.out
    mkdir -p build
t.out: $(OBJS)
    mkdir -p build
    $(CC) $(DBGFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o ./build/t.out
    size ./build/t.out

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf *.o ./src/*.o *.out ./build
```

When I do

```bash
make build
make build DBG=1
make build DBG=0
```

seems to not cause any difference and `DBG` variable is never changed to `1`.
If I force it `#define DBG 1` in **main.c** it works.

edit

```
DBGFLAGS = DBG
```

I perform a `make clean` everytime

`make DBG=1 build` outputs

```
    gcc    -c -o src/main.o src/main.c
    gcc    -c -o src/screen.o src/screen.c
    gcc    -c -o src/plus.o src/plus.c
    gcc    -c -o src/minus.o src/minus.c
    mkdir -p build
    gcc -DDBG ./src/main.o ./src/screen.o ./src/plus.o ./src/minus.o -o ./build/t.out
    size ./build/t.out
       text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
       2240     616      16    2872     b38 ./build/t.out
```

Comment: What happens if you do `make clean` in between?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show the complete output from building your code?

Comment: I don't see any code in the makefile to handle `DBG` being passed as a parameter. You should have `-DDBG=1` unconditionally.

Comment: This rule `$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c` is not working. It would make `src/main.o` out of `./main.c` but not out of `src/main.c`. Everywhere else `$(DBGFLAGS)` does nothing.

Comment: I perform make clean everytime

'make DBG=1 build'
results on
"gcc    -c -o src/main.o src/main.c
gcc    -c -o src/screen.o src/screen.c
gcc    -c -o src/plus.o src/plus.c
gcc    -c -o src/minus.o src/minus.c
mkdir -p build
gcc -DDBG ./src/main.o ./src/screen.o ./src/plus.o ./src/minus.o -o ./build/t.out
size ./build/t.out
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   2240     616      16    2872     b38 ./build/t.out"

Comment: `gcc -c -o src/main.o src/main.c gcc` Well you can clearly see this does not invoke the rule I mentioned (if still in doubt, change that rule, rebuild, and observe that the actual compilation command doesn't change).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI not sure how to fix what you saying, the compilation goes trough

Comment: The compilation goes through because there is a default make rule that takes care of it. But obviously it knows nothing about your custom flags, so you don't see them in there.

Comment: To see what rules are used by Make, run `make --debug=i build`.

Comment: Thank you @n.m.couldbeanAI 

I have at the moment removed the object creation and it works. 

I have added two switches for DBG and can pass it by command line.
Now need to understand how to use these rules for object file creation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you having variable DBGFLAGS, but trying to set DBG, which is not defined in Makefile.
You need:

```
make build DBGFLAGS="-DDBG=1"
make build DBGFLAGS="-DDBG=0"
//or
make build DBGFLAGS=""
```

And in principle you can remove following lines (i dont see much sense in them):

```
#ifndef DBG
    #define DBG 0
#endif
```